# AngularJS Как сгруппировать записи

Tags: angularjs

```
  <div ng-repeat="event in items">
    <li  ng-bind="toDate(event.date)">/</li>
    <li >
        <div>
            <div>
                <span ng-bind="toTime(event.date)">/</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <span ng-if="event.name != 'null'">{{ event.name }}</span>
                {{ event.number }}
            </div>

            <div>
  <span ng-if="event.size> 0">
    <a href="#" ng-click="click(event.rid)">Download</a>
      {{event.size}}
  </span>

                <div>
                    <a href=""  ng-click="show = !show;load(event.rid)">Show images</a>
                    <span id="list_photo" ng-show="show"></span>
                </div>
                {{event.txt}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Сам контроллер:

```
$http.get('http://site.com/device/api/{{ imei.imei }}')
.then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
```

В результате получаем массив с ответами:

```
    {"date":"04.10.2017 18:34:04", "name":"ivan","number":"9208109010","size":"123","rid":"1236711","txt":"биография"}
{"date":"04.10.2017 11:34:13", "name":"Stepan","number":"9108112010","size":"321","rid":"127821","txt":"биография"}
{"date":"05.10.2017 13:26:41", "name":"Mihail","number":"9301421050","size":"111","rid":"27373","txt":"биография"}

`toDate(event.date)` возвращает `04.10.2017`. 
toTime(event.date) возвращает  18:34
```

Так вот, необходимо сгрупировать записи по датам.

```
04.10.2017
18:34  Ivan 9208109010 123 1236711 биография
11:34  Stepan 9108112010 321 127821 биография
05.10.2017
13:26  Mihail 9301421050 111 27373 биография
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy)

```
$scope.grouppedItems = lodash.groupBy($scope.items, function(item) {
    // $scope.toDate должна вернуть дату в виде 04.10.2017
    return $scope.toDate(item.date);
});
```

После этого в `$scope.grouppedItems` будет такая структура

```
{'04.10.2017': [
    {"date":"04.10.2017 18:34:04", "name":"ivan","number":"9208109010","size":"123","rid":"1236711","txt":"биография"}
    {"date":"04.10.2017 11:34:13", "name":"Stepan","number":"9108112010","size":"321","rid":"127821","txt":"биография"}
], 
'05.10.2017': [
    {"date":"05.10.2017 13:26:41", "name":"Mihail","number":"9301421050","size":"111","rid":"27373","txt":"биография"}
]}
```

Вывод

```
<div ng-repeat="(date, items) in grouppedItems">
    {{ date }}
    <div ng-repeat="event in items">{{ event.name }}</div>
</div>
```

И можно будет вывести с помощью `ng-repeat`

Comment: $scope.grouppedItems добавил после $scope.items. Пытался что-нибудь вывести ng-repeat="event in grouppedItems".  lodash подцепил, в консоли пишет: ReferenceError: lodash is not defined и ничего не выводит.

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов попробуйте `_` вместо `lodash` и проверите что подключили его до вызова в контроллере.

Comment: Ошибка в консоли пропала, и вернулся массив. Не пойму теперь как  его вывести, чтобы записи были сгрупированны. ng-repeat="event in grouppedItems" ничего не выводит

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов добавил в ответ вывод

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что я коряво добавил $scope.grouppedItems и он походу просто не возвращает никакого результата. Массив возвращается из  $scope.items. Я правильно понимаю, что код с  $scope.grouppedItems просто прописывается после $scope.items?

Comment: $http.get('http://syncmobile.com/device/api/{{ imei.imei }}')
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(err){console.log(err)})

            $scope.grouppedItems = _.groupBy($scope.items, function(item) {
                return $scope.toDate(item.date);
            });

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов поместите сразу после `$scope.items = response.data;` но как в комменте выше. Так работать не будет естественно. Промисы асинхронные.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь